# Integral Test for convergence of a series

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, inequality, convergence-divergence

"Consider the series given by $$\sum_{n=2}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{n\ln n(\ln(\ln n))^{\alpha}}$$
for $\alpha>1$. Use the Integral Testo to conclude if the series is convergent or not."
I tried to make some computation involving inequalities of integrals of the function $f(x)=\frac{1}{x\ln x (\ln(\ln x))^\alpha}$, which is positive, continuous and decreasing, but I hadn't much success... The answer is "Yes, it's convergent."

Comment: For real $\beta > 0,$ what is the derivative of $(\log \log x)^{- \beta}?$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using integral test, have

$$\int_{x=2}^{x=+\infty} \frac{1}{xln(x)[ln(ln(x))]^{\alpha}} dx$$
Letting $u=ln(x)$ gives us $du=\frac{1}{x}dx$
$$\implies \int_{x=2}^{x=+\infty} \frac{1}{u[ln(u)]^{\alpha}} du$$
Now letting $w=ln(u)$ gives us $dw=\frac{1}{u}du$
$$\implies \int_{x=2}^{x=+\infty} \frac{1}{w^{\;\alpha}} dw$$
$$\implies \int_{x=2}^{x=+\infty} w^{\;-\alpha} dw$$
$$\implies \frac{w^{-\alpha +1}}{-\alpha+1}|_{x=2}^{x=+\infty}$$
$$\implies \frac{1}{(-\alpha+1)[ln[ln(x)]]^{\alpha -1}}|_{x=2}^{x=+\infty}$$

It is clear that our series converges.

Comment: Since $\ln (\ln 2)$ is negative, the function $\displaystyle f(x) = \frac{1}{x\ln x(\ln(\ln x))^\alpha}$ can be negative. Therefore we should use integral test on the sum starting from $n=3$, that is, $\displaystyle \sum_{n=3}^\infty \frac{1}{n\ln n(\ln(\ln n))^\alpha}$. Of course, this makes no difference to the overall convergence since the term when $n=2$ is finite.

Comment: Also, instead of making two substitutions, the single substitution $y = \ln(\ln x)$ will do the job more quickly.

Comment: lol yeah I realized after I finished writing it that that would've been easier.

Comment: Thanks guys! You have been very useful!

Comment: @Anderson: Remember that if you see this question on a test, you will need to justify/check that the function is positive, continuous, decreasing, etc. on the interval you want to use the integral test. Otherwise, your instructor may not aware you full marks even if you arrived at the correct answer.

Comment: Thanks @EWHLee! I'm really studying for a test. I'll follow your advice!